# How can I center a background using a CSS element?

Tags: css

How can I center a background using a CSS element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
background-position:center;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 5):

You can also use percentages, so

```
background-position: 50% 0;
```

would centre the background horizontally. The beauty of percentages is they offers greater flexibility than keywords. You can position a background a quarter of the way across the screen with,

```
background-position: 25% 0;
```

and a quarter of the way across and 3 quarters of the way down with,

```
background-position: 25% 75%;
```

Comment: I think you have a better answer. With center property you can accomplish have the entire image center BUT you will not able to adjust vertically... background:url(image.jpg) 50% -40px; for example..