# Center a Background Image in a DIV

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, how can I vertically and horizontally center a background image in a DIV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [center background-position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242948/center-background-position)

Comment: Please leave a constructive comment then you down-vote

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame: It's not a dupe

Comment: @Codemonkey How is it not a duplicate?

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame: Your linked question doesn't address how to vertically centre a background

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
div { background-position: center center; }
```